# query distinct mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, mysql-workbench

Tengo dos tablas:

alumnos(id_alumno, id_carrera, nro_doc... rterc, eterc) PK(id_alumno, id_carrera).

deudas(rterc, eterc, fecha_factura, nro_factura, importe, venc...)
no tiene claves la tabla deudas.

El campo eterc es igual al nro de documento.

Para sacar las deudas del alumno utilizo un sp así:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ALU_DEUDAS`(
    IN p_alumno varchar(50),
    IN p_rterc char(2),
    IN p_eterc char(15)
)
BEGIN
if p_rterc != '' and p_eterc != '' then
    SELECT d.* 
        FROM camp_deuda as d 
            INNER JOIN camp_alumnos as a 
                ON a.calu_rterc = d.rterc and a.calu_eterc = d.eterc
        WHERE a.calu_id_alumno = p_alumno AND d.rterc = p_rterc AND d.eterc = p_eterc;
end if;
END
```

Funciona perfectamente, el problema es cuando el alumno está inscripto en varias carreras. Me repite las facturas según las carreras que tenga el alumno.

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo? Pensé en hacer un `select distinct nro_factura`.
No sé que opinan ustedes. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo están relacionadas tus tablas? Normalmente deberías tener un campo en las filas de la tabla deudas que haga referencia a los alumnos, ejemplo `id_alumno` y el `JOIN` lo harías por ese id, en el caso que quieras  todas las deudas (facturas pendientes) del alumno. Por cierto, no estaría mal darle nombres más descriptivos a tus columnas. Pues si alguien hereda tu código tendrá que pasar una semana tratando de entender qué significan las columnas `rterc`, `eterc`... y otras por el estilo que pudieras tener por ahí.

Comment: si tienes id_carrera en ambas tablas solo tendrias que agregar en WHERE 
AND d.id_carrera = a.id_carrera.

Comment: si quieres el total yo lo haria un group by por id_alumno y id_carrera y en el select un sum SELECT SUM(campo_valor) , id_alumno
        FROM camp_deuda as d 
            INNER JOIN camp_alumnos as a 
                ON a.calu_rterc = d.rterc and a.calu_eterc = d.eterc
        WHERE a.calu_id_alumno = p_alumno AND d.rterc = p_rterc AND d.eterc = p_eterc GROUP BY a.id_alumno ,a.id_carrera;

Comment: Creo que no funcionaría ya que las facturas las duplica o triplica al estar inscripto en varias carreras el alumno.

Comment: No tiene claves la tabla deudas.Lo heredé y resolví varias cosas, pero esto no estoy pudiendo resolverlo.
Gracias

Comment: Hice lo mismo  y  agregué un group by (nro_factura) y ya no se repiten. 
qué opinan?